# Select Silverlight Treeview Item using MVVM Pattern

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, treeview, treeviewitem

Can anyone tell me,Please include code, how to select a treeviewitem using the MVVM Pattern

Comment: What do you mean by "select a TreeViewItem"?  Are there specific criteria you need to select by?  What are you trying to do with the item?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848987/cannot-seem-to-communicate-between-views/2849526#2849526) post had a code example that was using a Tree View, with MVVM suggestions.

I have the solution in a zip file to that I could send you (from the answer to the link) if you would like them.